# bash says '[[:' not found. what does that mean?

Tags: bash, sh

While running a bash script, I get this error:

```
 sh: [[: not found
```

How can I find what where is the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`[[` is a `bash` command that is not compatible with `sh`. Run the script with `bash` instead:

```
$ bash ./script.sh
```

Or edit the [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

then:

```
$ ./script.sh
```

Comment: Or put `#!/usr/bin/env bash` at the top of your script.